# "show more" option in bootstrap column expands all adjacent columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a website using Bootstrap. The desktop layout has 4 columns in each row (grid tiles like layout).
Every tile has some lengthy text which I managed to collapse using a jQuery plugin.

Now the problem I'm facing is that when the "show more" option is used the content of that tile expands, thus pushing the tiles below it downwards.
However, it also expands the tiles of all other columns too.
How can I prevent other column tiles form expanding their size?

I only want that column to get extended downwards in which a tile's "show more" option has been clicked.

**normal view**
[normal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovqiM.png)

**after clicking "show more"**
[after clicking "show more"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsqTb.png)

Comment: this is the [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jasonalvis/show-more) I used

Comment: This is how Bootstrap works. It has nothing to your plugin. When you expand one column - whole row is taller.

Comment: Just to clarify: you only want the left tile (where you clicked "show more") to expand, but you want the right part to keep its height?

Comment: Like this? http://oi64.tinypic.com/14ceib7.jpg

Comment: @S.F. yes that's how I want it

Comment: @makshh yeah, I realise that. But there has to be some workaround to the problem, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then your bootstrap layout is probably not correct. This structure should work:

```
<html>
    <head>
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:150px; border: 1px solid #fff; background:blue">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:400px; border: 1px solid #fff; background:blue">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:200px; border: 1px solid #fff; background:blue">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:200px; border: 1px solid #fff; background:green">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:200px; border: 1px solid #fff; background:green">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:200px; border: 1px solid #fff; background:green">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </body>
```

Here is also a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lp9e327s/

Comment: @johnwick: is the solution above working for you? If yes, could you please accept it? Cheers :)